# Polymer update style from child to parent

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have 2 elements. The first one called test-layout is using styles from `core-layout`

In test-layout:

```
<link rel="import" href="../commons/core-layout.html">
<style include="core-layout"></style>
<div class="containerTest">Test Layout Text</div>
```

In core-layout:

```
<style>

.containerTest{
    color: var(--color, blue);
}
</style>

<div class="containerTest">Core Layout Text</div>

<script>
_mediaChanged(e){

 if(this.mediaDetail.desktop){
        this.customStyle['--color'] = 'blue';
        this.updateStyles();
    }
    else if(this.mediaDetail.tablet){
        this.customStyle['--color'] = 'green';
        this.updateStyles();
    }
    else if(this.mediaDetail.mobile){
        this.customStyle['--color'] = 'red';
        this.updateStyles();
    }
}
</script>
```

`_mediaChange()` is using iron-media-query to notify me if the view is a desktop, tablet or mobile.  From there I change the font color

When I resize the page the text in `core-layout` changes but the text in `test-layout` (parent) doesnt.

**Tablet Size**

[image]

**Mobile View**

[image]

**Desktop View**

[image]

Is there a way for me to update the parent (test-layout)?  I want to use `core-layout` for styles that are media dependent and I don't want to have to copy all the styles to every component

---

**SOLUTION**

Ok I think I figured it out.  If I change the mixin from `test-layout` then it works.  I guess it has to go from parent to child only and not the other way around.  What I did was move the `_mediaChanged()` to `test-layout` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixins and CSS variables are parent > children related when you want to apply them, for updating the variable from children you need to have api in the parent which can apply the changes on themself and it will be changed all of it's childrens.

Your solution to move the `_mediaChanged()` method works because you moved the variable assigment to the parent element and all of it's children has the value from it